# Running Python script using os.system()

Tags: python

Are there any limitations when it comes to executing Python script using os.system() ?

In the script I'm importing pyfirmata library but it throws an error saying "no module named pyfirmata"

However, when I run a Python shell and type `import pyfirmata` no exception occurs. What's the catch ?

Comment: Are the Python versions running each the same? Try putting in a `print(sys.version)` in your script (you'll need to import `sys`), and compare that to the version you're using in the shell.

Comment: I'm using alias ... when I type python it triggers Python 3.5 automatically.

Comment: @PMende  Whoops !  I just added 3 to make it read `os.system('python3 script.py')` and it worked ! Dammit ... this one was stupid.

Comment: FYI, `os.system()` should be avoided in favor or `subprocess.call()`. The latter takes a list of the command name and its arguments. This avoids the overhead of an intermediate shell and is safer if there is any possibility at all of the command args containing shell metachars.

Comment: @KurtisRader  I'm implementing the subprocess.run(). However it doesn't work. I suspect permission to connect to serial port is denied. I think I've seen that error somewhere. I just don't know why I can run the script from shell without any trouble, but when I try to run it with subprocess.run() from Django view it throws this error.